Are we allowed to ignore the Bessel function of the second kind when solving Laplace's equation for an axisymmetric system?
I am looking at the solution to finding the potential of a thin disc of surface mass density $\Sigma(r)$ placed at $z = 0$. The system has cyclindrical symmetry. Outside of the $z=0$ plane there is no mass so $\nabla^2 \psi = 0$ where $\psi$ doesn't depend on the azimuthal angle. ie
$$\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}(r\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial r}) + \frac{\partial^2 \psi}{\partial z^2} = 0.$$
We then let $\psi = R(r)Z(z)$ and solve by seperation of variables. We get that $R(r)$ satisfies the Bessel equation (of order 0) ie its solutions are $J_0(kr)$ and $Y_0(kr)$. (The solution for z is an exponential, and we require the potential to vanish as $z$ goes to $\pm \infty$)
My lecture notes then go on to say that:
$\Psi (R,z) = \int_0^\infty f(k) \exp(-k|z|)J_0(kr)dk$
and we then relate $f(k)$ to $\Sigma$. I understand the logic behind taking an integral of all the possible solutions for $R,Z$ against a weighting function $f$. But is it strictly valid to ignore the $Y_0$ solutions? ie in my mind we should actually use:
$\Psi (R,z) = \int_0^\infty\exp(-k|z|)(f(k)J_0(kr) + g(k)Y_0(kr))dk$
for weighting functions $f,g$. But perhaps this reduces somehow to the first integral? Or maybe there is some implicit assumption about the behaviour of $R$ that allows us to discount the $Y$ solutions in this thin disc example?

whether you may or may not ignore $Y_0(kr)$ depends on the condition you set at $r=0$ because the function is singular there. If the axis is excluded from the problem space, say, you wish to solve only for $r>a$, then you need the boundary condition on $r=a>0$ and must include $Y_0$.

thanks @hyportnex !

also does anyone know why my question is downvoted? Is it formatting, the title or something else?
